# Can the word "genocide" be used as a verb? If it can't, what are the alternative verbs?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, verbs

[Here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genocide), on Wiktionary, it says we can use "genocide" as a transitive verb to mean "To commit genocide (against); to eliminate (a group of people) completely." In other dictionaries though, I couldn't find any descriptions that define "genocide" as a verb. In all of the dictionaries I looked at besides Wiktionary, there is not a definition of "genocide" as a verb. So I need to ask you if you think it is okay or usual to you to use "genocide" as a verb to mean "To commit genocide (against); to eliminate (a group of people) completely" like in "The bla bla bla nation genocided the bla bla bla nation." And if you think "genocide" is not okay as a verb, what verb should I use instead of it to mean that? You can provide alternative verbs for me even if you think it is okay to use "genocide".

Comment: to commit genocide.Use it as a transitive verb at your own risk. Criminal acts are committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, "to commit genocide" is alright. Though Wiktionary uses "genocide" as a verb and offers several examples, it sounds awful.

Alternatives that are verbs:
slaughter
decimate
annihilate
eliminate
exterminate

You should check each one in some dictionaries to see if it fits your need.